# invalid value for key attachdbfilename mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm doing a very basic MVC 4 project. I have a simple model and a dbcontext. I am trying to take input from a form and save it using the dbcontext.

Here's my codes,
In the controller

```
    public ActionResult FormShow(Models.bullseye sampbe)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var db = new bullseyeDataContext();
            db.bullseyes.Add(sampbe);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("FormShow");
        }

        return FormShow();
    }
```

In the dbcontext

```
public class bullseyeDataContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<bullseye> bullseyes { get; set; }

    static bullseyeDataContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<bullseyeDataContext>());
    }
}
```

And the connectionstring is

```
<add name="MvcFourFirstTouch.Models.bullseyeDataContext"
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
Integrated        Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MvcFourFirstTouch.Models.bullseyeDataContext.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And when i submit the form i'm getting invalid value for key attachdbfilename. Where's the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

The problem is with your connection string. `AttachDBFileName` does not like the value you've specified to it. Could be an issue with the db name, or an issue with LocalDB, or the lack/presence of an extra `\` in the paths.

However, if you have no explicit reason for using `AttachDBFileName`, then I would suggest replacing `AttachDbFileName=[...].mdf` with `Initial Catalog=yourDBName`. You avoid a lot if issues this way :)

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use `AttachDbFileName` specifically? If not, change `AttachDbFileName=[...].mdf` to `Initial Catalog=yourDBName`.

Comment: nice :D, it works fine this way,thanks... should i mark your answer accepted or edit then accept :s